# How to push teacher id /name to studentSchema in mongodb with nodejs ,expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to add favorite teachers id  to student schema  from list of teachers. So when the student clicks the "add favorite teacher " button, that particular teacher id will save in the student schema.

**Here is my student schema**

```
    const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
    const studentSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true}, 
    email:{type:String,required:true}, 
    phone:{type:String,required:true}, 
    password:{type:String,required:true},
    teacher : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID , ref:'teachers'}],
       
})

const studentModel = mongoose.model('students',studentSchema)
module.exports=studentModel
```

**Here is my teacher Schema**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')

    const teacherSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
        name:{type:String,required:true}, 
        email:{type:String,required:true}, 
        phone:{type:String,required:true}, 
        password:{type:String,required:true}, 
    })
    
    const teacherModel = mongoose.model('teachers',teacherSchema)
    module.exports=teacherModel
```

So what will be the backend route code to push the teacher id to Student schemas ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your student schema contains an instance of your teacher schema, not just the teacherID.  If your request will contain the studentID in params, and teacherID in its body, I would do something like the following.

I'd first create two middleware functions - one to ensure your returned studentID is valid.  Here the studentID is returned in the params via `req.params.id`.

```
import { studentModel } from "./models/student.js";


// middleware - check that student id exists
async function checkStudentIdExists(req, res, next) {
  let item;
  try {
    item = await studentModel.findById(req.params.id);
    if (item == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "cannot find student by given id" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
  res.student = item;
  next();
}
```

and the second to check that the chosen teacherID is valid.  Here the teacherID is returned via the body of the request, `req.body.id`

```
import { teacherModel } from "./models/teacher.js";

// check that teacher id exists
async function checkTeacherIdExists(req, res, next) {
  let item;
  try {
    const item = await teacherModel.findById(req.body.id);
    if (item == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "cannot find teacher by given id" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
  res.teacher = item;
  next();
}
```

In constructing the required route, use both middleware in a route, like this:

```
router.patch("/student/favoredTeacher/:id", checkStudentIdExists, checkTeacherIdExists, async (req, res) => {
  try { 
    await res.student.updateOne({teacher: res.teacher})
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
  }
});
```